# Proximo forwarding multiple IP

Tags: heroku, proximo

I'm using Proximo on my Heroku app, but need to forward only certain traffic through it, so after reading the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/proximo#configuring-the-proximo-wrapper), I added the IPs I wanted to forward, however it seems to remove the previous IP, so I'm only able to add one IP at a time.

Is there a way I can tell Proximo to forward multiple IPs? The documentation doesn't show this, but it may have been overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, I found the GitHub repository to the Proximo-stacklet which just 6 months ago allows for [multiple masks](https://github.com/pirateradio/proximo-stacklet/commit/3b2c41d803d7eaf41816e99ba6233d1333835b03#bin/proximo).

For anybody else looking for this, they need to be comma-separated.